# How to Securely Call Internal Functions from a Factory Contract in Solidity?

Tags: erc-20, tokens

I have two Solidity contracts: a token contract and a token factory contract. The token factory contract is responsible for deploying various tokens. Within the token contract, I have defined `mint` and `burn` functions as external, which internally utilize `_mint` and `_burn` functions, respectively.

Here's a simplified version of my token contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC20 {
    constructor(string memory name, string memory symbol) ERC20(name, symbol) {}

    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) external {
        _mint(to, amount); // Internal function
    }

    function burn(address from, uint256 amount) external {
        _burn(from, amount); // Internal function
    }
}

contract TokenFactory {
    function createToken(string memory name, string memory symbol) external {
        MyToken newToken = new MyToken(name, symbol);
        // How can I securely call the internal _mint and _burn functions from here?
    }
}
```

My issue arises from the fact that, because I'm using external functions for minting and burning, anyone can call these functions. This creates a security concern as it allows unauthorized users to manipulate the token supply.

My question is: How can I securely call the internal `_mint` and `_burn` functions in the token factory contract? Alternatively, are there better approaches to achieve this functionality?

I appreciate any insights or suggestions. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should restrict the access of `_mint` and `_burn` to be only available to the `TokenFactory` contract. You can do something like this, just tailor to your logic slightly, if needed:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC20 {
    address private immutable factory;
    constructor(string memory name, string memory symbol) ERC20(name, symbol) {
        factory = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyFactory {
        require(msg.sender == factory, "Sender is not the factory");
        _;
    }

    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) external onlyFactory {
        _mint(to, amount); // Internal function
    }

    function burn(address from, uint256 amount) external onlyFactory {
        _burn(from, amount); // Internal function
    }
}

contract TokenFactory {
    address private immutable owner;
    address private admin;
    constructor () {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Sender is not the owner of this contract");
        _;
    }

    function setAdmin(address newAdmin) external onlyOwner {
        admin = newAdmin;
    }

    modifier auth {
        require(msg.sender == owner || msg.sender == admin, "Caller not allowed to call this restricted function");
        _;
    }

    function createToken(string memory name, string memory symbol) external {
        MyToken newToken = new MyToken(name, symbol);
        // How can I securely call the internal _mint and _burn functions from here?
    }

    function reward(MyToken targetToken, address to, uint256 amount) external auth {
        targetToken.mint(to, amount);
    }

    function punish(MyToken targetToken, address from, uint256 amount) external auth {
        targetToken.burn(from, amount);
    }
}
```

---

That way the public functions will have restricted access, and will only be available to the authorized callers.